# Securely host native app web content (PHP scripts specifically)

Tags: php, ios, web-hosting

Forgive me if this has been asked before, but wasn't sure how to "word it", so wasn't able to find anything similar.

I have hosting with 1and1 (and the option to build my own web server). I am working on a native app that uses some WebKit WebViews to load web content. Some of this web content uses PHP scripts to connect to databases, or perform other functions.

My question is related to the storage of these scripts. I've read once that it was best practice to place these below root (/), but I can't see a way to do that with my 1and1 hosting. Another option is SSL (but there's costs for that).

What's the safest way to host php files for use in a native app disallowing direct navigation from a web browser/user ideally?

Thanks in advance SO.

Comment: If you don't want the files to be accessible, how will your app be able to use them?

Comment: valid - thought this myself. was thinking there was a way to "reference" a URL through xcode that would not be doable from the address bar of a standard browser. Probably not the case. .htaccess is another option I suppose.

Comment: There's not really anything you can do with htaccess that can't be bypassed rather trivially. The best you can hope for is using oauth or similar to authenticate the user.